# How to apply a html file as header with docx4j

Tags: java, html, docx4j

I'm generating a .docx file with a .html file using docx4j.
The html file is first converted in xhtml with jTidy.
This file is the body of my document.

I'm doing the same thing with the header, I have a file for this too.

I can generate a header and add it to my document, but only as plain text, not as html.

Here is my code for the header :

```
    //Header Part start
    HeaderPart headerPart = new HeaderPart();
    Relationship rel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(headerPart);
    String hdrXml = "<w:hdr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\">"
            + "<w:p>"
            + "<w:pPr>"
            //+ "<w:pStyle w:val=\"Header\"/>"
            + "<w:jc w:val=\"center\"/>"
            + "</w:pPr>"
            + "<w:r>"
            + "<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">" + myFileContentInString + "</w:t>"
            + "</w:r>"
            //  + "<w:fldSimple w:instr=\" PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT \">"
            // + "<w:r>"
            //  + "<w:rPr>"
            //  + "<w:noProof/>"
            //  + "</w:rPr>"
            // + "</w:r>"
            // + "</w:fldSimple>"
            + "</w:p>"
            + "</w:hdr>";

    Hdr hdr = (Hdr) XmlUtils.unmarshalString(hdrXml);
    wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(0).getHeaderFooterPolicy().getFirstHeader();
    headerPart.setJaxbElement(hdr);

    List<SectionWrapper> sections = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();

    SectPr sectPr = sections.get(sections.size() - 1).getSectPr();
    // There is always a section wrapper, but it might not contain a sectPr

    if (sectPr == null) {
        sectPr = objectFactory.createSectPr();
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(sectPr);
        sections.get(sections.size() - 1).setSectPr(sectPr);
    }

    HeaderReference headerReference = objectFactory.createHeaderReference();
    headerReference.setId(rel.getId());
    headerReference.setType(HdrFtrRef.DEFAULT);
    sectPr.getEGHdrFtrReferences().add(headerReference);

    //Header Part End
```

The xhtml content is in "myFileContentInString".

I couldn't be able to find something about this, so if somebody has any idea ?

EDIT : After your answer, I updated my code this way (here is the full code):

```
    String inputfilepath = "Offers/" + param.getKey1() + "_" + param.getKey2() + "/c.xhtml";
    String inputfilepath2 = "Offers/" + param.getKey1() + "_" + param.getKey2() + "/cc.xhtml";


    // Create an empty docx package
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    ObjectFactory objectFactory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();

    NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
    ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();

    XHTMLImporterImpl xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
    xHTMLImporter.setHyperlinkStyle("Hyperlink");

    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(xHTMLImporter.convert(new File(inputfilepath), null));

    //Header Part start
    HeaderPart headerPart = new HeaderPart();
    Relationship rel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(headerPart);

    Hdr hdr = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createHdr();
    hdr.getContent().addAll(xHTMLImporter.convert(new File(inputfilepath2), null));
    wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections().get(0).getHeaderFooterPolicy().getFirstHeader();
    headerPart.setJaxbElement(hdr);

    List<SectionWrapper> sections = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();

    SectPr sectPr = sections.get(sections.size() - 1).getSectPr();
    // There is always a section wrapper, but it might not contain a sectPr

    if (sectPr == null) {
        sectPr = objectFactory.createSectPr();
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(sectPr);
        sections.get(sections.size() - 1).setSectPr(sectPr);
    }

    HeaderReference headerReference = objectFactory.createHeaderReference();
    headerReference.setId(rel.getId());
    headerReference.setType(HdrFtrRef.DEFAULT);
    sectPr.getEGHdrFtrReferences().add(headerReference);

    // Saving file
    wordMLPackage.save(new java.io.File("Offers/" + param.getKey1() + "_" + param.getKey2() + "/html_output.docx"));
```

"inputfilepath2" contains the path fo my header xhtml file.
I tried to insert a simple Hello World in my header but it seems it is taking the "inputfilepath" for the body and the header.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reference to the correct headerPart, something like:

```
    Hdr hdr = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createHdr();
    hdr.getContent().addAll( 
            XHTMLImporter.convert( /* fill this in */ );
    headerPart.setJaxbElement(hdr);
```

Comment: I thought it was working, but it seems the file taken to make the header is the same as the the body one, despite having the good one declared.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  What is your updated code?